# String encoding (UTF-8) JAVA

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Could anyone please help me out here. I want to know the difference in below two string formatting. I am trying to encode the string to UTF-8. which one is the correct method.

```
String string2 = new String(string1.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
```

OR

```
String string3 = new String(string1.getBytes(),"UTF-8"));
```

ALSO if I use above two code together i.e.

```
line 1 :string1 = new String(string1.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")); 
line 2 :string1 = new String(string1.getBytes(),"UTF-8"));
```

Will the value of string1  will be the same in both the lines?

PS: Purpose of doing all this is to send Japanese text in web service call.
So I want to send it with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: String hold Unicode text, all possible scripts. If you get tje bytes for some more restricted encodeng/Charset, then a lossy conversion happens, normally resulting in `<?>` or question marks `?`. UTF-8 is a full Unicode charset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the javadoc of `String#getBytes(String charsetName)`:

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the named charset,
>   storing the result into a new byte array.

And the documentation of `String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)`

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using
>   the specified charset.

Thus `getBytes()` is opposite operation of `String(byte [])`. The `getBytes()` encodes the string to bytes, and `String(byte [])` will decode the byte array and convert it to string. You will have to use same charset for both methods to preserve the actual string value. I.e. your second example is wrong:

```
// This is wrong because you are calling getBytes() with default charset
// But converting those bytes to string using UTF-8 encoding. This will 
// mostly work because default encoding is usually UTF-8, but it can fail
// so it is wrong.
new String(string1.getBytes(),"UTF-8"));
```

Comment: got your point. but for second case where i am using the same string which was encoded using UTF-8 encoding in line 1 to get default bytes. So ideally the line 2 should also preserve string giving same string value which i was getting in line 1. Is it ryt?

Comment: I know this is wrong way of writing code as first line was sufficient. Since i am working on a legacy code that is having both the lines of code as mentioned in my question. until and unless these two lines can cause major issue at receiver end. I don't want to change it.

Comment: No, the second line can still fail to behave in expected manner if the default charset is not UTF-8. Because in the second line, when you write `string1.getBytes()`, it will encode the `string1` using the default charset, which may or may not be `UTF-8`.  And in the same line when you create new string using `UTF-8`, it will fail if default charset is not `UTF-8`, because in that case, the bytes are not encoded in `UTF-8`

Comment: Thanks. Any better to do it? or should i just use line 1 and remove line 2 in current code.

Comment: my string contains Japanese character

Comment: The right way is in the line 1. Use specific charset while encoding/decoding the string on both sides, i.e. sender / receiver. Don't rely on defaults.

Answer (score 3):

`String` and `char` (two-bytes UTF-16) in java is for (Unicode) text.

When converting from and to `byte[]`s one needs the `Charset` (encoding) of those bytes.

Both `String.getBytes()` and `new String(byte[])` are short cuts that use the default operating system encoding. That almost always is wrong for crossplatform usages.

So use

```
byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
s = new String(b, "UTF-8");
```

Or better, not throwing an UnsupportedCharsetException:

```
byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
s = new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

(Android does not know StandardCharsets however.)

The same holds for `InputStreamReader, OutputStreamWriter` that bridge binary data (InputStream/OutputStream) and text (Reader, Writer).

Answer (score -1):

Please don't confuse yourself. "String" is usually used to refer to values in a datatype that stores text. In this case, `java.lang.String`.

Serialized text is a sequence of bytes created by applying a character encoding to a string. In this case, `byte[]`.

There are no UTF-8-encoded strings in Java.

If your web service client library takes a string, pass it the string. If it lets you specify an encoding to use for serialization, pass it `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` or equivalent.

If it doesn't take a string, *then* pass it `string1.GetBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` and use whatever other mechanism it provides to let you tell the recipient that the bytes are UTF-8-encoded text. Or, get a different client library.